# Extract a single line from Multi line text data from a column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

Have a table address in Oracle with a column name details.
This column contains data something like this:

```
212 S Haw
City ABC
Pin Code
```

Ask is to write a query to fetch just the second line from this details column.
So I need a result which give me just City name which is in second line

Comment: Are you saying this is one row with embedded  newline characters?

Comment: Yes this particular data is one single column:
212 S Haw
City ABC
Pin Code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSTR` to find the position of the first and second newline character `CHR(10)` and then use `SUBSTR` to get the substring between those positions:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(
         value,
         INSTR(value, CHR(10), 1, 1) + 1,
         INSTR(value, CHR(10), 1, 2) - INSTR(value, CHR(10), 1, 1) - 1
       ) AS second_line
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
  SELECT '212 S Haw
City ABC
Pin Code' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| SECOND_LINE |
| --- |
| City ABC |

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/897230/1)